# How to solve Gem compatibly issues in Bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

In our rails application, we are using two gems (urbanairship and nylas) that's requiring `rest-client`. One wants `~> 1.6.7` and the other wants `~> 1.7.1`.

The usual `bundle udpate` and `rm Gemfile.lock; bundle install` doesn't work.

When `Bundler` is resolving dependencies, we are getting this:

```
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies............................................................................................................................................
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rest-client":
  In Gemfile:
    urbanairship (~> 3.0.1) ruby depends on
      unirest (>= 1.1.2, ~> 1.1) ruby depends on
        rest-client (~> 1.6.7) ruby

    nylas (>= 0) ruby depends on
      rest-client (~> 1.7) ruby
```

We can't use unfortunately a different version of either `nylas` or `urbanairship`. The only solution we are seing is forking one of the two and editing the `.gemspec` to accept the same version of `rest-client`.

Is there any easier solution?

Comment: You'll need to fork and relax the version requirements. However, those requirements usually exist because of specific behaviors in the required gems. Consider relaxing the requirement on urbanairship to `~> 1.6` and then `bundle update` and run its tests. If everything passes, then I'd commit that, use your fork in the Gemfile, and submit a pull request. :)

Comment: There are already two pull requests for the unirest gem at [#18](https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-ruby/pull/18) and [#22](https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-ruby/pull/22) which both relax the rest-client dependencies. None of them is merged yet unfortunately...

Comment: Remember you can deploy an arbitrary version of a gem using the `git` source specifier with a `ref` option for the hash to use. The [various `git` options](http://bundler.io/v1.3/git.html) cover a lot of cases that come in handy in situations like this. You don't need to fork the repository unless you need to make a change to the `.gemspec` file.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, ended up following Chris advice.

1. Forked `nylas`
   https://github.com/hartator/nylas-ruby/
2. Relaxed `Gemfile` requirements for `rest-client`. (was `1.7`)

   `gem 'rest-client', '~> 1.6'`
3. Relaxed `nylas.gemspec` requirements for `rest-client`. (was `1.7`)

   `s.add_dependency(%q<rest-client>, ["~> 1.6"])`
4. Relaxed `nylas.gemspec` runtime requirements for `rest-client`. (was `1.7`)

   `s.add_runtime_dependency(%q<rest-client>, ["~> 1.6"])`
5. Ran specs, everything was still passing.
6. Added the altered gem to my application `Gemfile`

   `gem 'nylas', git: 'git@github.com:hartator/nylas-ruby.git'`

Everything is working. Still wondering if there is a cleaner solution out there.

Ref: https://github.com/hartator/nylas-ruby/commit/f7ff4076e96d8a31e223ca0f12d35811d6e9d811